# Shadow disappears then reappears on UITableView updates

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, shadow

I am using tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates() to expand/contract a cell that has shadow. When the table updates, it removes all shadows from cells and then puts them back as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcAZm.jpg)

I have tried using willDisplayCell and also tried changing the shadow to its own view, shadow on contentView and shadow on cell, none worked.

How do i keep the shadow?

```
extension UIView {
    func addTutShadow(shadowOpacity: Float? = nil) {
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 12 * kHeightFactor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity ?? 0.12
    }
}
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = 
    tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TopicListCard
    cell.topic = rankedTopics[indexPath.section]
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.backgroundView = UIView()
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.addTutShadow()
    cell.setup()
    return cell
}

var selectedIndex = -1
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedIndex != indexPath.section {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.section
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    } else {
        selectedIndex = -1
        tableview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Please add some relevant code.

Comment: We need to see what you're doing to add the shadow.

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to say exactly, without seeing you full cell setup...

I whipped up a quick example of ***one way*** to do this...

Looks like this:

[image]

**Data Structs**

```
struct Topic {
    var title: String = ""
    var status: String = ""
    var icon: String = ""
}
struct TopicCellStruct {
    var topic: Topic = Topic()
    var expanded: Bool = false
}
```

**Simple gradient view** - for the background

```
class MyGradView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    private var gLayer: CAGradientLayer {
        return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        gLayer.colors = [
            UIColor(red: 0.71, green: 0.88, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1).cgColor,
            UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
        ]
        gLayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    }
}
```

**Example controller class** - with some sample generated data

```
class ShadowTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    var myData: [TopicCellStruct] = []
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        // some sample data
        let p1 = "You have correctly answered "
        let p2 = "% of the questions you attempted in this topic."
        var pct: Int = 5
        
        let titles: [String] = [
            "Basic Algebra",
            "Isolating a Variable",
            "Absolute Value",
            "Solving Linear Equations",
            "Solving Radical Equations",
        ]
        let syms: [String] = [
            "function",
            "multiply.circle",
            "ruler.fill",
            "arrow.up.arrow.down",
            "x.squareroot",
        ]
        for (title, sym) in zip(titles, syms) {
            pct += 4
            let s: String = p1 + "\(pct)" + p2
            let t = Topic(title: title, status: s, icon: sym)
            let tcs = TopicCellStruct(topic: t, expanded: false)
            myData.append(tcs)
        }
        for i in 6...9 {
            pct += 4
            let s: String = p1 + "\(pct)" + p2
            let t = Topic(title: "Title \(i)", status: s, icon: "\(i).circle.fill")
            let tcs = TopicCellStruct(topic: t, expanded: false)
            myData.append(tcs)
        }
        
        // a label above the table view
        let topUI = UILabel()
        topUI.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .regular)
        topUI.numberOfLines = 0
        topUI.text = "This is some text to represent the UI elements above the table view."

        // a gradient view for the background
        let gradientBKGView = MyGradView()

        [gradientBKGView, topUI, tableView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            gradientBKGView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            gradientBKGView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            gradientBKGView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            gradientBKGView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            topUI.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            topUI.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            topUI.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -48.0),

            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 160.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
        ])

        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        tableView.register(ShadowedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ShadowedCell.ident)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        
    }
    
}
extension ShadowTestVC: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ShadowedCell.ident, for: indexPath) as! ShadowedCell
        c.fillData(myData[indexPath.row])
        c.selectionStyle = .none
        return c
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let c = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ShadowedCell else { return }
        myData[indexPath.row].expanded.toggle()
        c.isExpanded = myData[indexPath.row].expanded
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
        })
    }
}
```

**Example cell class** - I made some guesses at your layout, and I set the shadow darker than yours (`.shadowOpacity = 0.75`) to make it a bit more visible.

```
class ShadowedCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    public static let ident: String = "sc"
    
    public var isExpanded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            expandedConstraint.isActive = isExpanded
            ivVerticalExpandedConstraint.isActive = isExpanded
            ivHorizontalExpandedConstraint.isActive = isExpanded
        }
    }
    
    private let titleLabel = UILabel()
    private let statusLabel = UILabel()
    
    private let theImageView = UIImageView()
    
    private let getStartedBtn = UIButton()
    
    private let containerView = UIView()
    private let shadowView = UIView()
    
    private var collapsedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var expandedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var ivVerticalCollapsedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var ivVerticalExpandedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var ivHorizontalCollapsedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var ivHorizontalExpandedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        containerView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        [shadowView, containerView, theImageView, titleLabel, statusLabel, getStartedBtn].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        [titleLabel, statusLabel, getStartedBtn].forEach { v in
            v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        }
        [titleLabel, statusLabel, theImageView, getStartedBtn].forEach { v in
            containerView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        contentView.addSubview(shadowView)
        contentView.addSubview(containerView)
        
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        shadowView.backgroundColor = .white
        
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)
        
        statusLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        statusLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .regular)
        
        getStartedBtn.setTitle("Get Started", for: [])
        getStartedBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        getStartedBtn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        getStartedBtn.backgroundColor = .black
        getStartedBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        collapsedConstraint = titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        expandedConstraint = getStartedBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0)
        
        ivVerticalCollapsedConstraint = theImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 5.0)
        ivVerticalExpandedConstraint = theImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusLabel.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        
        ivHorizontalCollapsedConstraint = theImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0)
        ivHorizontalExpandedConstraint = theImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16.0)
        
        collapsedConstraint.priority = .required - 2
        expandedConstraint.priority = .required - 1
        
        ivVerticalCollapsedConstraint.priority = .required - 2
        ivVerticalExpandedConstraint.priority = .required - 1
        
        ivHorizontalCollapsedConstraint.priority = .required - 2
        ivHorizontalExpandedConstraint.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            shadowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadowView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadowView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadowView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            
            statusLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            statusLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            statusLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),

            theImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
            theImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theImageView.widthAnchor),
            
            getStartedBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            getStartedBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            getStartedBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
            collapsedConstraint, ivVerticalCollapsedConstraint, ivHorizontalCollapsedConstraint,
            
        ])
        
        shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0)
        shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75
        shadowView.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
        
    }
    
    public func fillData(_ t: TopicCellStruct) {
        titleLabel.text = t.topic.title
        statusLabel.text = t.topic.status
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: t.topic.icon) {
            theImageView.image = img
        }
        isExpanded = t.expanded
    }
}
```

Give that a try... it *should* avoid the shadow issue you were seeing. Then compare my approach to yours.

As a side note: I'm sure you already noticed in your development... while the design is very nice with transparent cells and table view, the expand/collapse process looks a bit "quirky" as the cells that were "out of view" (below the bottom of the table view frame) don't really "slide up" along with the other cells.

---

**Edit** -- a couple of very minor changes to improve the "glitchy" lower-cells-animation...

[image]

**All classes***

```
struct Topic {
    var title: String = ""
    var status: String = ""
    var icon: String = ""
}
struct TopicCellStruct {
    var topic: Topic = Topic()
    var expanded: Bool = false
}

class ShadowedCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    public static let ident: String = "sc"
    
    private let titleLabel = UILabel()
    private let statusLabel = UILabel()
    
    private let theImageView = UIImageView()
    
    private let getStartedBtn = UIButton()
    
    private let containerView = UIView()
    private let shadowView = UIView()
    
    private var collapsedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var expandedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var ivVerticalCollapsedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var ivVerticalExpandedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var ivHorizontalCollapsedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var ivHorizontalExpandedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        
        clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        containerView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        [shadowView, containerView, theImageView, titleLabel, statusLabel, getStartedBtn].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        [titleLabel, statusLabel, getStartedBtn].forEach { v in
            v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        }
        [titleLabel, statusLabel, theImageView, getStartedBtn].forEach { v in
            containerView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        contentView.addSubview(shadowView)
        contentView.addSubview(containerView)
        
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        shadowView.backgroundColor = .white
        
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)
        
        statusLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        statusLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .regular)
        
        getStartedBtn.setTitle("Get Started", for: [])
        getStartedBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        getStartedBtn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        getStartedBtn.backgroundColor = .black
        getStartedBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        collapsedConstraint = titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        expandedConstraint = getStartedBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0)
        
        ivVerticalCollapsedConstraint = theImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 5.0)
        ivVerticalExpandedConstraint = theImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusLabel.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        
        ivHorizontalCollapsedConstraint = theImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0)
        ivHorizontalExpandedConstraint = theImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16.0)
        
        collapsedConstraint.priority = .required - 2
        expandedConstraint.priority = .required - 1
        
        ivVerticalCollapsedConstraint.priority = .required - 2
        ivVerticalExpandedConstraint.priority = .required - 1
        
        ivHorizontalCollapsedConstraint.priority = .required - 2
        ivHorizontalExpandedConstraint.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            shadowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadowView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadowView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            shadowView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            
            statusLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            statusLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            statusLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6),
            
            theImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
            theImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theImageView.widthAnchor),
            
            getStartedBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            getStartedBtn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            getStartedBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
            collapsedConstraint, ivVerticalCollapsedConstraint, ivHorizontalCollapsedConstraint,
            
        ])
        
        shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 3.0)
        shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75
        shadowView.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
        
    }
    
    public func fillData(_ t: TopicCellStruct) {
        titleLabel.text = t.topic.title
        statusLabel.text = t.topic.status
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: t.topic.icon) {
            theImageView.image = img
        }
        expandedConstraint.isActive = t.expanded
        ivVerticalExpandedConstraint.isActive = t.expanded
        ivHorizontalExpandedConstraint.isActive = t.expanded
    }
    
    public func expand(_ isExpanded: Bool) {
        expandedConstraint.isActive = isExpanded
        ivVerticalExpandedConstraint.isActive = isExpanded
        ivHorizontalExpandedConstraint.isActive = isExpanded
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

}
class ShadowTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    var myData: [TopicCellStruct] = []
    
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        // some sample data
        let p1 = "You have correctly answered "
        let p2 = "% of the questions you attempted in this topic."
        var pct: Int = 5
        
        let titles: [String] = [
            "Basic Algebra",
            "Isolating a Variable",
            "Absolute Value",
            "Solving Linear Equations",
            "Solving Radical Equations",
        ]
        let syms: [String] = [
            "function",
            "multiply.circle",
            "ruler.fill",
            "arrow.up.arrow.down",
            "x.squareroot",
        ]
        for (title, sym) in zip(titles, syms) {
            pct += 4
            let s: String = p1 + "\(pct)" + p2
            let t = Topic(title: title, status: s, icon: sym)
            let tcs = TopicCellStruct(topic: t, expanded: false)
            myData.append(tcs)
        }
        for i in 6...19 {
            pct += 4
            let s: String = p1 + "\(pct)" + p2
            let t = Topic(title: "Title \(i)", status: s, icon: "\(i).circle.fill")
            let tcs = TopicCellStruct(topic: t, expanded: false)
            myData.append(tcs)
        }
        
        // a label above the table view
        let topUI = UILabel()
        topUI.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .regular)
        topUI.numberOfLines = 0
        topUI.text = "This is some text to represent the UI elements above the table view."
        
        // a gradient view for the background
        let gradientBKGView = MyGradView()
        
        [gradientBKGView, topUI, tableView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            gradientBKGView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            gradientBKGView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            gradientBKGView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            gradientBKGView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            topUI.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            topUI.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            topUI.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -48.0),
            
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 160.0),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
        ])
        
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        tableView.register(ShadowedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ShadowedCell.ident)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        
    }
    
}
extension ShadowTestVC: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ShadowedCell.ident, for: indexPath) as! ShadowedCell
        c.fillData(myData[indexPath.row])
        c.selectionStyle = .none
        return c
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let c = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ShadowedCell else { return }
        myData[indexPath.row].expanded.toggle()
        c.expand(myData[indexPath.row].expanded)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

class MyGradView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    private var gLayer: CAGradientLayer {
        return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        gLayer.colors = [
            UIColor(red: 0.71, green: 0.88, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1).cgColor,
            UIColor(red: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1).cgColor
        ]
        gLayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: wow i really appreciate this! Will try and let you know

Comment: @MichaelMontalbano - I made a couple (very minor) edits to improve  the "glitchy" lower-cells-animation... see the **Edit**